# What is the difference between RL78.EW.COMPILER and RL78.EW.COMPILER_STD?

Tags: iar

when trying to run a specific .exe file, I get the error message concerning an IAR Compiler license problem:

*Fatal error: License check failed. Use the IAR License Manager to resolve the problem. No license found. [LicenseCheck:2.13.4.627, RMS:8.5.0.0021, Feature: RL78.EW.COMPILER, Version:1.01] Fatal error detected, aborting.*

In the IAR License Manager there is a License for "RL78.EW.COMPILER_STD" (Version 1.02) listed. In how far do these both differ? May I use the "RL78.EW.COMPILER_STD" to run this file?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a valid and legal license, contact IAR support, they are very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already been helped by IAR support by now, but just in case anyone else wonders the same thing:

The "_STD" part of the feature name is just a license package tag. An .exe requiring a license for feature RL78.EW.COMPILER, version 1.01 can use any license RL78.EW.COMPILER_X, version 1.01 or greater.